# delete Items from Json File that doesn't have keys ~ Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, key

I have a JSON file and would like to remove a certain book

```
[
  {
    "title": "How to love",
    "author": "vagabondage3",
    "isbn": 9832,
    "genre": "Comedy",
    "numofcopies": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "How to eat",
    "author": "belabor",
    "isbn": 2345,
    "genre": "Documentary",
    "numofcopies": 3
  },
  {
    "title": "hwo",
    "author": "TafaTIC",
    "isbn": 19,
    "genre": "Comedy",
    "numofcopies": 9
  }
]
```

Part to remove

```
{
    "title": "hwo",
    "author": "TafaTIC",
    "isbn": 19,
    "genre": "Comedy",
    "numofcopies": 9
  }
```

the json file should look like this in the end

```
[
  {
    "title": "How to love",
    "author": "vagabondage3",
    "isbn": 9832,
    "genre": "Comedy",
    "numofcopies": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "How to eat",
    "author": "belabor",
    "isbn": 2345,
    "genre": "Documentary",
    "numofcopies": 3
  }
]
```

I honestly saw a similar example but I can't understand it can you explain please how it was done thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it depends how you identify which one you want to delete. If you want to delete by index, you could try this:

```py
json_data.pop(2)
```

Or you could just iterate with a condition:

```py
json_data = [item for item in json_data if item['title'] != 'hwo']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in multiple ways:
You can use `del` operator to remove a certain book by index:

```
del data_json[2]
```

Or, You can use pop() method:

```
data_json.pop(2)
```